# GDAL doesnot support HDF4 e

Tags: gdal, modis, hdf, pymodis

I am trying to import the pymodis library within python and I keep getting error that

**"GDAL installation has no support for HDF4, please update GDAL"**

I am running the latest version of GDAL [Version: 1.11.2+dfsg-1~exp2] and tried runnign the update command too. But still the same error persists.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and using the terminal to run  python.

[image]

Comment: In http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135867/gdal-hdf4-driver-on-linux-system is not the answer. I don't have installed **libhdf4-alt-dev** and **libhd4-dev** in my Debian system and it has HDF4 support when I import **pymodis**. I think that is enough only with the packages **libhd4-0** and **libhd4-0-alt** because I have this support.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on 14.04, what have you tried?

```
apt-get install libhdf4-dev 
apt-get install proj-bin 
apt-get install libproj-dev 
apt-get install libgdal-dev 
apt-get install gdal-bin
```

This is a broad simplification, but: GDAL is geared to use what you have in your system. If I have libhdf4-dev installed and then I install GDAL, my GDAL 'comes with HDF4 support'.

Comment: I tried to run the command below provided in the pymodis documentation page for a start and when I tried it I got that error.  "modis_download.py -f 2012-12-05 -O -t h28v05,h29v05,h28v04 /tmp" . I ran the commands you gave above too but still the error exists.

Comment: Which version of **GDAL** are you using ? Does it come with hdf4 support ?

Comment: Well, GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10 but that's kind of not the right question - GDAL is geared to use what you have in your system. If I have libhdf4-dev installed and then I install GDAL, my GDAL comes with HDF4 support. This is on Linux, but it's kind of similar on Windows if you use OSGeo4W.

Comment: In Debian 8, I have installed GDAL 1.10.1, libhd4-0, libhd4-0-alt and pymodis (without libhdf4-alt-dev and libhd4-dev) and I doesn't get any error when it is imported pymodis library in python.

Comment: @mdsumner . Thanks for your answer, I tried removing gdal-din and python-gdal and then installed all the above (libhdf4-dev,proj-bin,libproj-dev,libgdal-dev) and then installed gdal-bin and python gdal again since it was mentioned above that GDAL uses what is available. *BUT* no luck yet

Comment: Can you check that GDAL has the driver, then maybe it's Python not picking it up properly? Using the gdal-bin that you installed use: gdalinfo --formats | grep HDF4
Other than that it might be a python special thing, dunno

Comment: Well the issue has been solved. I unistalled the pymodis package and installed it directly from the github and then ran a upgrade command  ... **sudo pip install git+https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis.git --upgrade**